# With recurring donations, PayPal gives an error "Things don't appear to be working at the moment. Please try again later."

Tags: html, paypal

PayPal is giving an error with recurring payments.  This is my form:

```
<html>
<form method="post" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Test Donation">
<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="2">
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="CAD">
<input type="hidden" name="tax" value="0">
<input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-DonationsBF">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="68YARP6A6VWY6">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick-subscriptions">
<input type="hidden" name="src" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="a3" value="7">
<input type="hidden" name="p3" value="2">
<input type="hidden" name="t3" value="W">
<input type="hidden" name="modify" value="1">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</html>
```

PayPal gives me an error saying "Things don't appear to be working at the moment. Please try again later."

I think I have followed the instructions on this page correctly, but maybe not.
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/#recurring-payment-variables

Can anyone tell what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that PayPal decided to not let subscribers modify their subscriptions anymore, so the "modify"="1" was the problem.  I changed that to "0", and it all works.